# Is there a constant expression that is not a core constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr, compile-time-constant

According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), a `constant expression` is not bound to be a `core constant expression`.

My question:

**Is there a `constant expression` that is not a `core constant expression`?**

Comment: What do you mean by "a `constexpr`"? `constexpr` is a keyword that means two different things, depending on where it is used.

Comment: Also, where does that website say that there are constant expressions that are not core constant expressions?

Answer (score 4):

[[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#5) defines "constant expression" as:

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
>   expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression
>   whose value satisfies the following constraints: [...]

There is no such thing as a constant expression that isn't a core constant expression, and cppreference doesn't claim otherwise.

Comment: ...which is to say the answer is: no. Note in the quote above (from Section 11 of [expr.const]) that *constant expressions* are defined in terms of *core constant expressions* - i.e. every *constant expression* is a *core constant expression* by definition.

Comment: It is interesting that while that definition comes from Section 11 of [expr.const] ... usages of the term "constant expression" occur throughout [expr.const] - starting at Section 2.2. I wonder if all those usages are specifically "constant expressions" rather than "core constant expressions"...especially as the introductory clause at Section 1 introduces the section topic as "constant expressions" (rather than "core constant expressions").

Answer (score 1):

[expr.const] lists a whole series of things that are not *core constant expressions*.  These include signed integer overflow (65536 * 32768 on a 32 bit machine), division by zero, and certain shift operations.

Comment: Is `constexpr int n = 1 / 0;` a `constant expression` but not a `core constant expression`?

Comment: @xmllmx - No, the expression `1/0` is not a core constant expression and therefore is not a constant expression.